# Usar espaço extra além do reservado pelo "malloc()"

Tags: c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Quando solicitamos uma quantidade de memória ao sistema e utilizamos muito mais que o solicitado o que acontece? Fiz esse teste e o código aqui compilou normalmente.

A princípio funcionou como deveria, queria saber o que isto implica, acredito que isso não é uma coisa que se faz, mas para fins didáticos queria entender sobre.

```
int main(){
    player *p = (player*) malloc(5 * sizeof (player));

    for (int x=0;x<15;x++){
        p[x].id = 10 + x;

       std::cout << "Endereço: " << p + x<< std::endl;
    }

    for (int x=0;x<15;x++)
         std::cout << "Endereço: " << p + x << ", Valor: " << p[x].id << " ou " << (p + x)->id << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O código está incompleto. O segundo for, por exemplo, não tem as chaves `{}`; não há declaração de `player`.

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira, For, If, Else, etc. são comandos de controle de fluxo que executam apenas o próximo comando, quando tivermos que executar apenas um comando, não há necessidade de chaves, o que acontece quando queremos que mais de um comando seja executado como resultado de um desvio de fluxo é que o próximo comando é um bloco, um bloco, esse bloco é considerado o próximo comando e portanto é ele que será executado, portanto nenhum problema ai. E dado o contexto e a pergunta, não é necessário a declaração de _player_.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

> quando solicitamos uma quantidade de memória ao sistema e utilizamos muito mais que o solicitado o que acontece?

Você escreve em uma área não reservada para isso e passa por cima de outra coisa, obviamente criando sérios problemas para a aplicação já que o valor que estava lá é perdido. A pior coisa que pode lhe acontecer é funcionar, porque está errado, mas parece que não. É assim que boa parte das invasões de sistemas ocorre.

Nesse caso não aconteceu um problema porque não tem outra coisa na memória, mas nenhum código real é assim.

Da mesma forma que não liberou memória, neste caso não tem importância, mas em código real possivelmente haveria problemas.

Funcionar é diferente de estar certo.

[image: Carro Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Geralmente não se usa `malloc()` em C++.

Answer (score 2):

Quando utilizamos muito mais do que a memória que alocamos, simplesmente o Sistema Operacional não saberá que o que está sobrando pertence ao seu programa e qualquer outro processo poderá usar este espaço, então no meio da execução do programa os dados que estão além do que o que você alocou podem ser modificados e transformados em lixo. No Windows geralmente não costuma dar problema de compilação, mas utilizando uma ferramenta de análise de memória como **Valgrind**, você perceberá **muitos** erros.

Alocar Memória significa dizer ao Sistema Operacional: "Proteja um espaço de memória pra mim de forma sequencial, e me dê o endereço do início deste bloco que você alocou, porquê eu já sei o tamanho e posso manipular manualmente, apenas proteja este espaço para que nenhum outro processo use esta memória até que meu processo finalize ou a libere."

Liberar Memória é o oposto, você não apaga os dados que estão lá, **inclusive, sabendo o endereço, se nenhum outro processo modificou os dados, é possível que outro processo consiga acessar os dados que estavam armazenados no endereço criado por outro processo**, e isso seria considerado lixo para outros processos, enquanto que no contexto da sua execução ele serve para algum propósito.

Liberar Memória é dizer para o Sistema Operacional: "Agora pode permitir que qualquer processo use o espaço de memória que se inicia no endereço X, de tamanho N"